# [SymmetricDS]: Multiple row from source write only one row to target

Tags: symmetricds

I have a table where multiple record with PK ID, EffectiveDate. When send to target, I only need the latest record. My PK in target is only ID. How can I achieve this ?

source

ID EffectiveDate

P1 2018-01-01

P1 2018-02-01

target

ID EffectiveDate

P1 2018-02-01 (latest)

Answer (score 0):

If both rows ID values are the same then I would declare the column as the primary key at the target database and leave subsequent insert statements fallback to update overwriting the effective date column with the latest value.

Comment: But at source I want EffectiveDate also as PK so I can insert multiple record

Comment: Do not change anything at the source database. Only declare the ID as the primary key at the target database.

Comment: My PK at source is (ID, EffectiveDate), PK at target is (ID) it does not allow me to update at target, if I insert second row with same ID. I already use transform Update_first = 1

Comment: Detected conflict while executing INSERT on dbo.Test.  
The primary key data was: {ID=P1, EffectiveDate=2018-01-01 00:00:00.000}. Failed to fallback.  
The original error message was: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Test'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Test'. The duplicate key value is (P1).

Comment: You could declare then a conflict detection with resolution newest wins

Comment: How do I declare this ?

Comment: I try but still same error: INSERT INTO SYM_CONFLICT (CONFLICT_ID, SOURCE_NODE_GROUP_ID, TARGET_NODE_GROUP_ID, TARGET_TABLE_NAME, 
DETECT_TYPE, DETECT_EXPRESSION, RESOLVE_TYPE, PING_BACK, RESOLVE_CHANGES_ONLY, RESOLVE_ROW_ONLY, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATE_BY, LAST_UPDATE_TIME) 
VALUES ('test', 'corp', 'store','test', 
'USE_TIMESTAMP', 'EFFECTIVEDATE', 'NEWER_WINS', 'REMAINING_ROWS', 1, 1, current_timestamp, 'administrator', current_timestamp);

Comment:  I'm not sure you need the column DETECT_EXPRESSION

Comment: if USE_TIMESTAMP then it need, else what could I use ?

Comment: Should be possible to insert null

Comment: If I left it null, Could not find a timestamp column with a name of  on the table dbo.Test.  Please check your conflict resolution configuration

Comment: For DETECT_TYPE try using USE_PK_DATA

Comment: I think Update_first is enough to solve the error.. previous not work is because I mixed up the source and target node...